# Why is the allowance 10**8 inside the test but equal to zero in the smart contract?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, testing, erc-721, allowance

I'm running this test:

```py
def test_mint(prf, exValue, web3):
    wBtcAddress = "0x2260FAC5E5542a773Aa44fBCfeDf7C193bc2C599"
    ABI = [{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"mintingFinished","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"_token","type":"address"}],"name":"reclaimToken","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[],"name":"claimOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_subtractedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseApproval","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[],"name":"finishMinting","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_addedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseApproval","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"pendingOwner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[],"name":"Pause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[],"name":"Unpause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":True,"name":"burner","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Burn","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":True,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Mint","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[],"name":"MintFinished","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":True,"name":"previousOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipRenounced","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":True,"name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":True,"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":True,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":True,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":True,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":True,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}] 
    wBTC = web3.eth.contract(address=wBtcAddress, abi=ABI)
    minter = accounts[0]
    god = accounts[1]
    wBTC.functions.approve(prf.address, exValue).transact({'from': str(minter)})
    allowance = wBTC.functions.allowance(minter.address, web3.toChecksumAddress(prf.address)).call()
    assert allowance == exValue
    prf.mintNewPetRock(minter, "Fabio", 10**8).transact({'from': str(minter)})
    assert prf.totalSupply().call() == 1
```

which throws this error:

```bash
E       brownie.exceptions.VirtualMachineError: revert: You need to check token allowance
E       Trace step -1, program counter 2196:
E         File "contracts/v2/PetRockNFT.sol", line 36, in NFT.mintNewPetRock:    
E           require(_amount == exchangeValue, "You need to send 1 BTC");
E           uint256 allowance = wBTC.allowance(_msgSender(), address(this));
E           require(allowance == 0);
E      >>>  require(allowance >= exchangeValue, "You need to check token allowance");
E           wBTC.transferFrom(_msgSender(), god, _amount);
E           uint256 _tokenId = totalSupply();
E           super._mint(_to, _tokenId);
```

Why is the allowance equal to 0 in the smart contract but equal to exValue (10**8) inside the test?

source code: https://github.com/lucadonnoh/petrock

### Tests I did:

#### 1)

```
event msgSenderEvent(address indexed sender);

function msgSender() public {
    emit msgSenderEvent(_msgSender());
}
```

returns `minter` (0x66) address as expected

#### 2)

```
//<tests>
require(_msgSender() == 0x33A4622B82D4c04a53e170c638B944ce27cffce3);
require(allowance == 0);
//</tests>
```

both pass but 0x33 is `god` address, the deployer, not `minter`

## EDIT:

```
prf.mintNewPetRock(minter, "Fabio", 10**8, {'from': str(minter)})
```

works instead of

```
prf.mintNewPetRock(minter, "Fabio", 10**8).transact({'from': str(minter)})
```

for some unknown reason

Comment: What's `_msgSender()` value?

Comment: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/GSN/Context.sol

Comment: I know the function, but what's the value returned?

Comment: how can i find out?

Comment: Store the value in a temporary variable, or use step by step debugger like remix to trace the value. I don't see any obvious mistake. Does wBtc point to the right address?

Comment: i've added a function that emits an event with _msgSender(), which i found out is the minter's one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117895/discussion-between-donnoh-and-ismael).